# LinkedIn login is not working from my application in Samsung?

Tags: android, linkedin-api, samsung-mobile

i develop one app in that i am using LinkedIn integration to share text and image it is working very fine in HTC mobiles but it is not working in all Samsung mobiles. please solve my problem

my java code..

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LinkedInPost.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**LinkedInPost.java**

```
public class LinkedInPost extends Activity 
{
    // initializations

    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "key-key-key";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "key-key-key";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "techgene";
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;


    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;

    private String strLinkedInMessage;
    private String strLinkTitle;
    private String strLink;

    //Called when the activity is starting.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linkedin);

        strLinkedInMessage  =   "04.17pm";
        strLinkTitle        =   "testing";
        strLink             =   "http://184.173.113.66/images/deal/rest_2012_3_18-0_1_27309-oysters-01.jpg";

        liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        try
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
            startActivity(i);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

/** 
 * Method to verify the authentication, As it is used only in this package, it is made protected 
 */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
        client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
        client.postShare(strLinkedInMessage, strLinkTitle,strLink, strLink,VisibilityType.CONNECTIONS_ONLY);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "In Try +ve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onNewIntent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finish();
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".LinkedInPost"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="techgene"
            android:scheme="x-oauthflow-linkedin" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

this code working fine in htc but not working in samsung in logcat i errors like this

```
10-02 06:16:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(11708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.LinkedInPost}: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.linkedin.com
10-02 06:16:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(11708): Caused by: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: api.linkedin.com
10-02 06:16:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(11708):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
10-02 06:16:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(11708):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:497)
10-02 06:16:07.312: E/AndroidRuntime(11708):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you want to call `api.linkedin.com` responses with a 404 on my end of the net.
You should check whether you called the correct endpoint for OAuth.

Aside from answering your question, you should not post your OAuth credentials on any website.

Comment: Are you sure that you have internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must have solved the problem But I guess I must reply it
:) I have spent week in a wired problem in my case. Please make sure that your device time is correct because linkedin server will not accept the wrong time and will give error.